# Weird problem when asking a question in Area51

Tags: support, area-51, spam

I can't find the meta for Area51 and I don't know if usability issues can be asked about in the Discussion zone, so I am asking here

I wanted to make a post in the [Korean Language and Usage proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) at Area51 but it doesn't let me. After playing around for a while it seems that the problem is that after a certain number of Korean characters are entered the system starts acting up for some reason.

[image]

Adding anything after the underlined part in the picture above causes it to give the error as shown. The word "Proposal" is the first word in the post (which gets added automatically by the way, when making a post for a particular proposal) and not necessarily the cause of the error (I changed it with the word "Topic" and the error is still the same, viz, Body cannot contain "Topic"). On top of that it snarkily tells me to take my spamming elsewhere.

Why isn't it posting my message?

Comment: We have blocked Hangul in much of the network following very persistent Korean spam. This is an unfortunate fallout from this block.

Comment: Is there any kind of workaround?

Comment: Is this ban effective in chat as well, or just the main sites?

Comment: We are trying to get a chat room going in order to promote the Korean Language proposal. If this ban persists then it might cause problems

Comment: I believe chat isn't effected. I am also looking at lifting the block on Area51.

Comment: @user13267 there is no workaround, it's a low level server block. Only a dev can remove the block.

Comment: I replaced the text with a screenshot for the moment though

Comment: @Oded how come it's not a bug? It's blocking valid questions from being submitted. (sample or not, it's still basic part of Area 51)

Comment: @user13267 by the way, since you mentioned it, Area 51 does have its own "meta", called [Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/), and it even got a [bug tag](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) there. Such critical bugs, which prevents basic actions, better be reported here though, as you did, since the team pays much more attention to this site. (aka MSE :))

Comment: @Sha - it was placed there for a reason. It is a known consequence.

Comment: @Oded so the second best thing is changing from bug report to feature request, asking to remove the block from Area 51, or at least from that specific proposal - this way you can mark it [tag:status-completed] when done. Know it's nitpicking, but can't help it.. :)