# Unable to edit question, claims 'Body cannot contain "i.stack.imgur.com"'

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, error-message

**Edit** It works now.

I'm trying to retag [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/35336/11591) question on skeptics via https, but I can not save the question because the system complains

```
Body cannot contain "i.stack.imgur.com"
```

[image: screen shot]

What's going on here?

Comment: Strange, it only seem to be happening on Skeptics, on MSE, SU and on SO I can't repro

Comment: I had a similar problem in Area51 when I was trying to get http://korean.stackexchange.com/ created

Comment: are there non English characters in this post?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268509/221878

Comment: @user13267: I can't find any.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is experiencing this error then try any of the following:

1. Reupload, re-set the image
2. Format the body section (this worked for me when I removed unnecessary spaces)
3. If the error persists, answer without the image and upon editing the error disappears.