# Meta Stack Exchange is blocking posts containing Korean characters, on question about Korean language Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, meta, quality-filter, spam-detection

This is the error that I am getting

[image: The error says "Body cannot contain" followed by Korean characters used in the question]

[I have seen something like this before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268509/weird-problem-when-asking-a-question-in-area51) when trying to get the Korean language Stack Exchange created in Area 51, and it was due to some spam protection measure, but that was a few years ago and it looks like the problem hasn't been resolved yet.

Is there anything that can be done about this? Is it possible to allow posts from older active accounts perhaps? [This is the question I am trying to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358653/how-does-stackexchange-search-for-non-english-words-work-or-korean-specifically), if anyone is interested.

Comment: The Chinese character spam filter is disabled on this site, and I thought the Korean character one was also disabled here; it seems like that's a bug.

Comment: [Relevant link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263725/377214) regarding unblocking of Chinese characters on some specific sites; it seems the same needs to be implemented for Korean characters here.

Answer (score -2):

How about adding images with your question? I can see already your question with Korean on the image.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion. You can't copy/paste the characters in an image, nor search for them, nor change the font, nor use a screenreader, nor edit.

Comment: But I think it's better than it can not ask anything.